# Does Insertion Sort always take N-1 comparasons on a sorted list?

Tags: sorting, insertion-sort

I just finished the old "Sorting Detective" homework (where you are given a few black box sorting algorithms and have to determine what example each one is by the results), and I noticed that Insertion Sort always took N-1 comparisons on a sorted list. Since I won't be able to look at my instructor's code until everyone has turned in their assignments, nor am I allowed to ask questions in class that could tip off the other students as to how to proceed to solve the problem, this left me with a question I can't get the answer to this question for at least a week.

Is it always the case in the real world that a textbook example of Insertion Sort will do N-1 comparisons on a sorted list, or is it quirk of my instructor's/textbook's version of Insertion Sort?

After searching Google and the Wikipedia, I couldn't find the answer to this, which means either I'm asking the wrong question or they just don't have it. Any ideas?

Comment: To find the "insertion point" on an ordered list (size N) you'll need log(N) comparisons. To insert one item you should first search (log N) and than insert/"shift up"(N/2) moves := N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a “textbook” insertion sort will perform N-1 comparisons if the input is already sorted.  See for example Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 3, §5.2.1, Algorithm S (*Straight insertion sort*).  For each record R<sub>i</sub> (i > 1), the algorithm compares it against elements R<sub>i-1</sub> down to R<sub>1</sub>, in that order, until it finds an element smaller than R<sub>i</sub>.  If the input is already sorted, then R<sub>i-1</sub> is always smaller than R<sub>i</sub>, so the algorithm only performs one comparison per record (and no comparisons for record 1).

Of course, you could write insertion sort to perform the comparisons in order from R<sub>1</sub> to R<sub>i-1</sub> instead, but that would perform N*(N-1)/2 comparisons if the input list were already sorted.  So don't do that. :)

You could also use a binary search to find the location at which to insert each record.  This is called *binary insertion*, and Knuth also discusses it in §5.2.1.  Again, it will perform more comparisons on an already-sorted input than textbook straight insertion (but fewer on random input).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know. I'm especially happy, as my instructor is now on a business trip, so I wouldn't have gotten the answer for yet ANOTHER week.